# How can I use different kerberos principals for sudo than for system-auth?

Tags: rhel, sudo, pam, kerberos

At my organization, we're required to use different kerberos principals when authenticating for sudo than for other types of auth, such as logging in.  For instance, my regular (login) principal might be called `foobar@DOMAIN`, whereas my sudo principal is called `foobar/sudo@DOMAIN`. In the past, we've met this requirement by building our own sudo with the `--with-kerb5` and `--enable-kerb5-instance=sudo` flags set at build time.  This means that our version of sudo hooks directly into kerberos, never using the PAM stack at all.

We're trying to see if we can meet the split-principal requirement without building and distributing our own build of sudo.  My question is: Is this possible, and if so, how?

Using the standard RHEL 6/7 sudo package, I can't use the `--with-kerb5` build-time option; I have to use PAM as my authentication stack.  That means I must use `pam_krb5`.  With `pam_krb5`, I've noticed that I can map usernames to principal names in `/etc/krb5.conf` using the `appdefaults/pam/mappings` configuration option.  This gets me partway there, as it enables me to map a username of `foobar` to a principal name of `foobar/sudo`.  However, from what I can tell, there's no way to set mappings per application (kerberos sees PAM as a single application, no matter which application is invoking the PAM stack), meaning the mapping applies to any applications that use `pam_krb5` in their PAM configuration.  So I can get the system to use the sudo principals for both sudo and login, or login principals for both, but I can't get the system to use sudo principals for sudo and login principals for login.

Any ideas?  Or am I stuck with having to build & distribute a custom sudo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but I wonder if you could accomplish this using SSSD.

The `pam_sss` module lets you restrict a service to only considering particular domains in `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`. From `pam_sss(8)`:

> **domains**
>
> Allows the administrator to restrict the domains a particular PAM
>   service is allowed to authenticate against. The format is a
>   comma-separated list of SSSD domain names, as specified in the
>   sssd.conf file.

In theory, you could have two domains both pointing at the same upstream authentication environment, but with different rules for mapping users to principals.

Unfortunately, it looks like SSSD only supports static mappings of usernames to principal names, which doesn't scale very well.

**Update**

It also looks like more recent versions of the `pam_krb5` module support an `alt_auth_map` option that does *exactly* what you want.  That is, in `/etc/pam.d/sudo`, I can do this:

```
auth    required    pam_krb5.so alt_auth_map=%s/sudo only_alt_auth
```

...and now `sudo` will always use the `<username>/sudo` principal for authentication.

This version of `pam-krb5` is distributed with Ubuntu, but presumably one could build an rpm and install it on your systems without too much fuss.

Comment: I can configure `pam_krb5` to restrict a service to a particular domain as well, so I'm not sure I'm buying anything by using `pam_sssd`. And I'm not sure if I can do custom mappings on a per-domain level (I inferred from my reading of the man page that mappings is a global configuration option). I like this idea, though. I'll look into it and see if it leads anywhere.

Comment: So, "SSSD domain" != "Kerberos domain".  An SSSD "domain" basically means "a section of the configuration file", and you can have multiple domains pointing at *the same* Kerberos domain. This is *different* from what you can do with `pam_krb5`.  User <-> principal mappings are definitely *not* global options (they are per SSSD domain). I don't know for certain it will work, but I think it might.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying now.  I read too quickly and I thought you meant using SSSD to restrict a service to a particular Kerb domain.  This sounds promising.

Comment: Hmmm, looks like I may be able to perform dynamic mapping using the `full_name_format` option in a `domain` block of `sssd.conf` (I'm looking at a man page on RHEL 6.7).  Where were you seeing that SSSD only supports static mappings?

Comment: I was referring to the `krb5_map_user` option (see the `sssd-krb5` man page).  I wasn't aware of `full_name_format`, so if that works, bonus!  Also, see the update I am about to leave on the answer.

Comment: I saw that update - looks like *exactly* what I need - unfortunately, I don't see the `alt_auth_map` option to `pam_krb5` on RHEL 6.7 or 7.1 :( (and building our own `pam-krb5` package would just be laterally transforming our original problem)

Comment: I ended up solving my problem.  Basically, the approach that I'm using is to "proxy" kerberos through `pam_sss` for one service (login) and use `pam_krb5` directly for another service (sudo).  This way I can use different `appdefaults` sections for the two services and take advantage of separate `mappings` attributes for each service. I'll write up my solution and add it to your answer tomorrow.